# Section command does not work

Tags: sectioning

The following LaTeX code works fine on my laptop, but doesn't on my friend's computer. We are both using Texmaker.
The problem seems to be the section command, which gives me the error message:
"Missing number, treated as zero"
and
"Illegal unit of measure (pt inserted)"

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV = 15, titlepage,bibtotoc]{scrreprt}

\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier,avant}
\usepackage[pdftex]{graphicx}
\usepackage[font=footnotesize,bf,sf]{caption}
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\parindent0pt
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wallpaper}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{titlesec, blindtext, color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}
\newcommand{\hsp}{\hspace{20pt}}
\titleformat{\chapter}[hang]{\Huge\bfseries}{\thechapter\hsp\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hsp}{0pt}{\huge\bfseries}


\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage} 




\begin{document}
\chapter{works}
\subsection*{Doesn't}
Why not?
\end{document}
```

What could be the problem here?

Comment: `titlesec` and `fancyhdr` and KOMA --- oh my ;-)

Comment: it gives an error in texlive 2016 presumably your laptop has older versions of one or more of the packages.

Comment: Removing `titlesec` (and `\titleformat`) will cure the problem, but don't use `fancyhdr` with KOMA or drop KOMA. `hyperref` should be the last package to be loaded here, not somewhere in between

Comment: Update!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 5):

Do not use package `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class. It is possible to get the same format of the chapter heading using KOMA-Script commands.

```
\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \thechapter\hspace*{20pt}\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hspace*{20pt}%
}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge\rmfamily}
```

Additional remarks:

- Use the new syntax for option `bibliography=totoc`.
- Remove option `pdftex` for package `graphicx`.
- If there should be a `\parskip` instead `\parindent` to mark new paragraphs use the class option `parskip` with one of the values `full`, `half` etc. (see the KOMA-Script documentation).
- There is no need to load package `caption` in your example. You can change the font of the captions and their labels using `\addtokomafont` or `\setkomafont`.
- `hyperref` should be the last package.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV = 15,titlepage,
  bibliography=totoc % <- changed syntax
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier,avant}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <-remove option pdftex
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % <- do really want no paragraph mark?
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \thechapter\hspace*{20pt}\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hspace*{20pt}%
}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge\rmfamily}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}% <- instead using package caption
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries\sffamily}% <- <- instead using package caption

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\renewcommand{\chaptermark}[1]{\markboth{#1}{#1}}
\renewcommand{\sectionmark}[1]{\markright{#1}}
\fancyhf{}
\fancyhead[L]{\leftmark}
\fancyhead[R]{\rightmark}
\cfoot{\thepage} 

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}% last package

\begin{document}
\chapter{works}
\subsection*{Doesn't}
Why not?
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}%
  \caption{A caption}%
\end{figure}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Note that if you are using `fancyhdr` with a KOMA-Script class, you have to redefine `\fancyhead` and `\fancyfoot` (like in your code) to remove the old font commands like `\sl` etc.

But the recommended package for headers and footers in a KOMA-Script document is `scrlayer-scrpage`.

```
\documentclass[12pt,DIV = 15,titlepage,
  bibliography=totoc % <- changed syntax
]{scrreprt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{fourier,avant}
\usepackage{graphicx} % <-remove option pdftex
\usepackage[onehalfspacing]{setspace}
\setlength{\parindent}{0pt} % <- do really want no paragraph mark?
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{textcomp}
\usepackage{wallpaper}

\usepackage[top=1in,bottom=1in,left=1in,right=1in]{geometry}

\usepackage{color}
\definecolor{gray75}{gray}{0.75}

\renewcommand\chapterformat{%
  \thechapter\hspace*{20pt}\textcolor{gray75}{|}\hspace*{20pt}%
}
\addtokomafont{chapter}{\Huge\rmfamily}

\addtokomafont{caption}{\footnotesize}% <- instead using package caption
\addtokomafont{captionlabel}{\bfseries\sffamily}% <- <- instead using package caption

\usepackage[autooneside=false,automark,headsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\clearpairofpagestyles
\ihead{\leftmark}
\ohead{\rightmark}
\cfoot*{\pagemark}
\addtokomafont{pageheadfoot}{\upshape}
\renewcommand\chaptermarkformat{}
\renewcommand\sectionmarkformat{}

\usepackage{blindtext}% dummy text
\usepackage{hyperref}
\begin{document}
\chapter{works}
\subsection*{Doesn't}
Why not?
\begin{figure}[htb]
  \centering
  \rule{3cm}{2cm}%
  \caption{A caption}%
\end{figure}
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

Maybe you can remove package `wallpaper` too because you can define an additional layer to use a background image.

---

If you really want to use `titlesec` together with a KOMA-Script class and you have the `titlesec` version 2.10.2 then you must install the [prerelease of KOMA-Script 3.20](http://www.komascript.de/node/1801). If your `titlesec` is version 2.10.1 you have to update this package too.

Comment: One for you :-) ["Page intentionally left blank" article](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/307346)

Comment: Nice, it works now. Also seems like I need to clean up my messy preamble.... Thanks!