# "Page intentionally left blank" article

Tags: formatting

How would I create a "page intentionally left blank" wherever I wish to put one?  Specifically, I'd like to place a page like that between the title page and ToC, and between the list of figures and main matter.  I'm currently using

```
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
```

to keep them blank, but I'd like to add that identifier.

I've looked through this article pretty thoroughly, [How do I make pages which were "intentionally left blank"?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1727/how-do-i-make-pages-which-were-intentionally-left-blank?rq=1), and I'm not sure what is specific to scrbook and what could be used generally.

MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  ...
\end{titlepage}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{empty}\newpage
... 
\end{document}
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 8):

Here is a suggestion using `scrlayer` to define an layer page style for these pages:

```
\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    foreground,
    %textarea,% use only the textarea
    contents={%
      \parbox[b][\layerheight][c]{\layerwidth}
        {\centering The space above and below the message
          intentionally is left blank.}%
    }
  ]{blankpage.fg}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{blank}{blankpage.fg}
```

Note that you can still use a package of your choice for the other headers and footers of the other pages. In the example below `fancyhdr` is used.

```
\documentclass[12pt,letterpaper]{article}

\usepackage{scrlayer}
\DeclareNewLayer[
    foreground,
    %textarea,% use only the textarea
    contents={%
      \parbox[b][\layerheight][c]{\layerwidth}
        {\centering The space above and below the message
          intentionally is left blank.}%
    }
  ]{blankpage.fg}
\DeclarePageStyleByLayers{blank}{blankpage.fg}

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\begin{document}

\begin{titlepage}
  \Huge Titlepage
\end{titlepage}
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{blank}\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\tableofcontents
\newpage
\listoffigures
\newpage\null\thispagestyle{blank}\newpage
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: To avoid the contradiction when stating that the page are intentionally left blank, when it obviously is not left blank, I write: ‘_The rest of the page intentionally is left blank_’. Since your are centring the message, maybe the message should state that the space above and below the message intentionally is left blank.